# How to position an image to stretch with the background image

Tags: css, image, css-position

I am trying to make a company logo always stay in the top left hand corner of the screen no matter what size the screen is. I do not want to use the fixed element positions as i dont want the image to scroll with the screen. My background already stretches automatically to size of the screen and therefore depending on the size of the screen the logo moves. Please let me know ideally using CSS

Comment: Can you show us some code and screenshots?

Comment: I am using a website page builder where it gives you the margins to keep your elements but the background image is set to stretch depending on the size of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `position: absolute;` in your Logo styles

And style it with `Left, Right, Top, Bottom` Properties.

You can read more about  `position: absolute;` in W3Schools : [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Comment: i have tried this and it technically works keeping the logo in the top left corner of the page but as the background image stretches depending on the size of the screen the logo does not stretch with the background image so gives it the appearance that the logo is no longer in the middle of the page. i think i need to connect the background image and the logo together ?